# add hebrew annotations to pdf files

Tags: perl, pdf

I'm adding annotations to a pdf file using the perl module [`PDF::API2::Annotation`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2::Annotation)

I'm having problems with adding them in hebrew.
I'm using this line to set the encoding to utf 8 :

```
my $font = $pdf->corefont('Times-Roman',-encode=>"UTF-8");
```

But still it didn't show up in hebrew, I'm using the notepad++ editor, and when I choose the editor encoding to UCS-2 it did work. But only if the hebrew part was inside the code itself.

But I'm getting the hebrew comments from an outside source (someone else is running my script and sending it paramaters using ARGV).

I tried using the encode detect, and I get that both of the variables (the one insidy my code written in hebrew, and the one im getting in the ARGV) are both UTF-8.

But still only the one inside my code will show up in hebrew in the pdf.
Any suggestions?

this is a sample of the code im using:

```
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::API2::Annotation;
use Encode;
require Encode::Detect::Detector;
use Encode qw(decode encode);

my $pdf = PDF::API2-> open (@ARGV[0])
my $page = $pdf -> openpage(@ARGV[1]);
my $font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica',-encode=>"UTF-8");
my $locationx = (@ARGV[2]);
my $locationy = (@ARGV[3]);
my $text = (@ARGV[4]);

my $annot = $page -> annotation;
$annot->text($text,-rect => [$locationx,1,1,$locationy]);
$pdf->saveas(@ARGV[5]);
```

Comment: Can you output the Hebrew chars that you get as arguments back to STDOUT correctly?

Comment: well default stdout is cmd, and cmd doesnt support hebrew charcters, but i tried to output them to a regular txt file and i get them correctly

Comment: it looks like thie line has no effect:
my $font = $pdf->corefont('Times-Roman',-encode=>"UTF-8");

also using the encode or decode functions has no effect, the only thing having an effect is the way i save the code in the editor, while using notepad++ , saving in UCS2 gives me hebrew, and saving in notepad in UNICODE also gives me hebrew comments on the pdf, BUT neither of them gives me hebrew comments when getting the hebrew comments from an outside source no matter how i try to manipulate them

Comment: Well you need to use the `$font` somewhere. You created a font object with it. You are not telling PDF::API2 to use it for anything. Can you show a small example of your code?

Comment: You need to [edit] the question. In comments use back ticks ```.

Comment: I took a quick look at the source of PDF::API2::Annotations. Doesn't look like it supports setting the font at all. You should look a bit deeper. Maybe you can hack it in and supply a patch.

Comment: do you know of any other module i can use to add anootations to a pdf (doesnt have to be perl)? this is the only one i found after searching quit a bit on google